# What libraries are available to manipulate JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, json

I have a webpage that uses JavaScript to retrieve JSON from a web service.  The JSON could contain 10 records or 100 records.  On the webpage, I want to provide a flexible interface that would allows the user to filter and order the data.  The filtering/ordering data should be processed in the browser.  I do not want the web service to do the filtering, because a round trip to the server would be need for each action and this seems very inefficient.

I have experience with JQuery, but the solution does not need to depend of JQuery.

Many of the options I like pertain to LINQ in JavaScript.  Below is a list of JavaScript libraries that are based on LINQ; I also added the date the library was last updated.  Is there a standard that the industry is using?

- [linq.js - LINQ for JavaScript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) (Jan, 21, 2011)
- [JSINQ - LINQ to Objects for JavaScript](http://jsinq.codeplex.com/) (Apr, 4 2010)
- [LINQ to JavaScript](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) (Jun, 16 2009)

Whichever library is decided on, it needs cross browser supported.

I’m not requiring that the library must be compatible with JQuery, or require that it must use LINQ’s syntax.  But I do like JQuery and the flexibility that LINQ provides.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the whole point of JSON is that it is native in javascript; sort of like Perl data Dump and Python pickling.

Comment: So are you looking for something that does data manipulation or a UI for data manipulation?

Comment: Linq for Javascript... now that just can't be fast :) but it is certainly interesting. But as for your basic premise, doing this at the server is inefficient, I'm not sure I agree -- generally. It doesn't sound like you have a lot of data here, but I would think that anything involving much more than what can reasonably be displayed on the screen is better left to the server. And since it's all algorithmic computation, the coding will be a lot easier.

Comment: @Bardev , once you recieve the data , you have manipulate the UI but don't expect json to do that....sorting etc should happen at the backend not UI...if you want to manipulate those things you should use datagrid.

Comment: I'm not looking for UI tools. I'm going to create custom Javascript to do the data manipulation.  I'm looking for recommendation for libraries that allows me in JavaScript to manage this data better.

Comment: @siri: If the data (100 records) is already on the client, then it seems inefficient to go back to server just to request a different way to order the data.

Comment: First, thanks for the comments. Based on the comments, I may have not phrased this question correctly.  I may need to delete the question and reword it.  If I don't get any valid answers in the next hour or so, I may do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important point is that JSON data is simply a JavaScript object so you can use any library that allows you to manipulate objects.

I would recommend [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as a general utility belt for these kind of issues.

This way we can manipulate data easily

```
var jsonData = $.getJSON(url);

var filtered = _.filter(jsonData, function(val, key) {
    if (val > 10) return true;
});

var sorted = _.sortBy(jsonData, function(val, key) {
    return order(val);
});
```

Filtering and ordering relies on your data model. I recommend you use some kind of wrapper to represent your data model on the client.

```
var MyModel = function(json) {
    var data = json;

    this.filterBySize = function(size) {
        data = _.filter(data, function(val) {
            return val > size
        });
    };

    ...
}

var model = new MyModel(json);
model.filterBySize(10);
```

An alternative is to use a large library like [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and creating a `Backbone.Model` for your record and a `Backbone.Collection` for your entire data set. Then you can simply call `.sort`, `.sortBy`, `.filter` on your Collection.

If your going to bring backbone out then your moving towards clientside MVC and you can use the entire toolset to connect your data and your UI together nicely. Just overwrite `Backbone.sync` with your own server communication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This may be a good alternative option to using a LINQ syntax library.  My current website is built on top of ASP.NET MVC, so I understand the MVC concept.  I have not heard of of Backbone and after doing some searches, this may play perfect for with my application.

Comment: @BarDev the main advantages of backbone is that its lightweight and the view is completely loose from the DOM so you can implement rendering in your own way. There are other MVC solutions like [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/), [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/). These are more tightly coupled to rendering techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Check this linq library just published yesterday and it's very powerful

https://github.com/iabdelkareem/LINQ-To-JavaScript